# SharePoint Designer for Mac?

Tags: sharepoint, macos, sharepoint-designer, remote-desktop

I'm looking for some way of editing SharePoint ASPX pages on my Mac, using either a local text editor or some kind of remote-into-the-SP-server solution (like emacs with tramp). I know that Cyberduck has the ability to open WebDAV servers with NTLM authentication, but I've been unable to get that to work.

So far, the only solution I've found is to use a remote desktop connection to a Windows Server, and run SharePoint Designer from there.

Anyone know of either a better method, or a SharePoint Designer alternative?

Comment: Correct.  Adding the "http://" let's the Mac know that it's actually connecting to a WEBDAV share.  Which is what SharePoint uses to make itself available as a "mapped drive".

Comment: As you note below, it's possible to do it via Finder. There, if you have proper permissions, it's like navigating a native MacOS volume, where you can use the code editor/IDE of your choice. It will probably the be the most effective way moving forward, since SharePoint Designer is EOL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Finder, I was able to mount the server by just selecting Connect To Server and prepending http:// to the server name. This prompted me for domain and user name, and works.